# Error while migrating project from Xcode 10.3 to Xcode 11.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to migrate swift project from Xcode 10.3(swift 4.2) to Xcode 11.5(Swift 4.2) but getting error. The below error I get when I run the project first time.

[image: This error I get when I run the project]

and if I fix this error by setting the Build Distribution property to "NO" then I get the below error. [image: Error after fixing the above error]

Now I want to set the Build Distribution property to Yes and want to fix the bridging header issue. I have explored for all the possible solutions but unable to find the right one which could fix it. Please help.

This is my podfile
[image]

Comment: change swift version of your pod paymentsdk

Comment: @RuchiMakadia. check the edited question.. have attached the podfile screenshot

Comment: How do you install `PaymentSDK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your `PaymentSDK` is old.

First remove the old framework and follow below steps to get a new one and update it.

**For Swift**

- Download the sdk from [here](https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_iOS_App_Kit/tree/master/Swift). You have an option to download bitcode enabled and disabled SDK
- Open your project in XCode and from File menu, select Add files to "yourproject"
- Select Paytm.framework in the directory you just unzipped
- Make sure 'Copy items if needed' is checked and Click 'Add'
- Under "Link Binary With Libraries" in the "Build Phases" tab of your project settings, add SystemConfiguration.framework
- Check if PaytmSDK.framework is added in both “Link Binary With Libraries” and “Embedded Binaries”. If not, add by clicking on the plus icon

Referemce from [here](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/ios-sdk/).